# Factory Boy - Reference a field inside a SubFactory

Tags: python

Say We have the following Django models:

```
class School:
    name: str

class Subject:
    name: str
    school: School

class Lesson:
    school: School
    subject: subject
```

And the following data exists in the tables.

```
School = ["ABC School"]
School = ["DEF School"]

Subject = ["Maths", "ABC School"]
Subject = ["Maths", "DEF School"]
```

How can I create a Lesson that grabs the subject of THAT school?

```
class LessonFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    school = SubFactory(SchoolFactory)
    subject = SubFactory(SubjectFactory, school=SelfAttribute('school.id'))  # something like this - this doesn't work

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
```

I am currently getting the error, `MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Subject -- it returned 2!`
as it got both school's Maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `"..school"`, so that it lazily evaluates it.

```py
class LessonFactory(DjangoModelFactory):
    school = SubFactory(SchoolFactory)
    subject = SubFactory(SubjectFactory, school=SelfAttribute('school')) 

    class Meta:
        model = Lesson
```

See: https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/540